# javax.jms.ConnectionFactory only connecting when logged in a root

Tags: java

I am executing the following code on a RHEL 6 box as root and it runs perfectly. But when i execute it as any user with lesser permissions i get a javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tride: [remote://myserver::myport]. It seems like a permission issue but i have all of the files my program accesses set to 777.

What could be causing this to happen?

Update apparently it does not resolve the host name to ip address unless i am root. Now i am using the ipaddress instead (I will use Iputils to resolve later). Now i am getting the follwoing errors:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:587)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:107)
        at myclass.run(myclass.java:172)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:863)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:583)
```

```
InitialContext context = null;

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.port", hostPort);
properties.setProperty("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://" + hostAddr + ":" + hostPort);
properties.setProperty("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
properties.setProperty("jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");
properties.setProperty("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS", "true");
properties.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
properties.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPass);
try
{
  context = new InitialContext(properties);

  ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactory);
  Destination destination = (Destination) context.lookup(jMSTopicName);

  Connection conn = cf.createConnection(userName, userPass);
  Session sesh = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  MessageConsumer consumer = sesh.createConsumer(destination, selector + selectorNum);
  consumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to host on restricted ports such as 80?

Comment: jms is on 4447. I have a jboss web services on 8080.